# How to move 100 Lambda functions from one region to another region in fast way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have **100 Lambda functions** one AWS **one region** along with API Gateway.
Now I want to **shift these functions in another region with API Gateway**, Shifting one by one will take more time to deploy all lambda and APIs.

So, can somebody suggest a better and faster way to achieve this will very helpful.

Comment: Were they generated by an AWS CloudFormation template, or were they created by hand? Have you tried writing a script that calls `get_function()` and then tries creating new functions with `create_function()`?

Comment: Are you using the serverless framework? You could try running the deployment in the new region and then deleting the old regions gateway and lambdas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes you created all of your resources manually in the AWS console.

You could create a new CloudFormation stack and import your API Gateway and any supporting resources (lambdas, databases, etc...) by following this guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html#resource-import-new-stack-console

Now, open the stack in the CloudFormation console, go to the **Template** tab and click on **View in Designer**

[image: Top of the Template Tab]

In the page that opens up, click the **Create Stack** button.

[image: Create Stack button]

Now this part is a bit of a hack, but in the browser's URL you'll see the current AWS region, replace this with the region that you want to deploy to and press enter. If you don't know the region name, [this list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html#Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.Availability) is a good reference.

[image: Current Region]

Now you can step through the wizard to setup your new stack. You will be asked to enter Parameter values, you can just copy them from the original stack that you created.